# Webview tag not working in Electron, even if tag enabled

Tags: javascript, html, electron

So I have been trying to make a simple electron app that uses a `<webview>` tag, but it's not working at all for me. I already had a little google around and found out that the webview tag needs to be enabled when creating the window.

I used electron-forge to create the boilerplate code. This is the function in `index.js` that creates the window with `webviewTag` enabled:

```
// Create the browser window.
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
        webviewTag: true
    }
});
```

This is the code I have in `index.html` that is supposed to just show a webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <web-view src="https://github.com" style="display:block; width:700px; height:480px"></web-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I have a look through the dev-tools the webview is definetly there and has the dimensions that I set. So it isn't just a case that the webview is just not visible. 
Another weird thing is that when I start the app it opens the dev-tools (not surprising as it is in the code), but the page has also a dark background color. Once I close the dev-tools the page becomes white for some reason.
I have some screenshots of this here:
[dev-tools open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPr07.png)
[dev-tools closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTgDO.png)

Thanks for reading and thanks in advance for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: Do [read the warning](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#warning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tag should be `<webview ...` instead of `<web-view ...`

Comment: Oh well that is a stupid mistake :D
Thanks for the help, I would have never found it by myself whoops